# Play an audio file on the recording stream

Tags: linux, audio, kubuntu

I basically want to play an audio file to the recording stream so other people can hear the audio. I am using a 20.04 Kubuntu.
Is there any easy way to do that?
I tried sox but it didn't seem to work for some reason.

Thank you.